# Page Break with Group Header in Birt

Tags: reporting-services, birt

I have a table with Group Header, the tables are grouped on *"Country"* names. So every country has own table. What I want is a page break when a country table is finished, not starting a second country table on the same page. It is possible to arrange this with **Birt Page Break** property, one can choose the option page break before the group header or after the group header, this works. But the problem is if I choose option "After" after the last country table there is an empty blank page. If I choose the option "Before" there is a blank page before the first country table. Which looks bad in the report. So how can I avoid this unnecessary blank page with having the feature page break after each country table except the last?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, when I was working on this case a month ago there wasnt an option "Always Excluding Last" or "Always Excluding First". Although nobody didnt update or touch my workspace Im surprised how these 2 options came...